# Setting rows as fieldnames in pentaho

Tags: excel, pentaho, transformation, data-integration

I am importing an excel file that imports as the following: [image]

Highlighted in red is what I want to appear as the fieldnames and first row.
However as you can see it creates a new row for field names and keeps in the irrelivant information (not highlighted in red).

I am unsure how to go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want to take row with IFS_num = Maximo database fields and use it as header row? Anyway, structure looks a bit weird.

Comment: yes, it's fine i've figured out a way to do this in a batch file before using pentaho